# Ошибка при установке illuminate/html

Tags: laravel, composer, terminal

Разбираюсь с фреймворком laravel. В консоле пишу:

```
composer require "illuminate/html"
```

В итоге вот что пишет консоль:

```
Using version ~5.0 for illuminate/html
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
- Installation request for laravel/framework == 5.0.16.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.16].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel требует наличия PHP расширения mcrypt.

Как установить в Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install php5-mcrypt
mv -i /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/
php5enmod mcrypt
service apache2 restart
```

Для других систем см. [мануал](http://php.net/manual/ru/mcrypt.setup.php)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно обновить composer:
`composer self-update`

Answer (score -1):

Нужно удалить папку кеша в хомяке:

```
  cd ~/ 
  rm -rf ./composer/cache
```

И запустить команду для обновления composer:

```
  composer global update
```